# What's is the equation of sinusoidal function on cylinder perimeter

Tags: geometry, functions, generating-functions

How can I determine the equation of a sinusoidal function that instead of proceeding on a horizontal line, proceeds along the perimeter of a cylinder while its sinus also lies on the surface area of the cylinder, like radially squeezing the cylinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *cylindrical coordinates* 
$$
z = h\sin \left( {\lambda \theta  + \alpha } \right)
$$

where:
 - $h$ is the amplitude of the sinusoid;
 - $r$ is the radius of the circular cylinder around the $z$ axis;
 - $\lambda$ is the angular speed  of the sinusoid (n. of repetitions along one turn around the cylinder);
 - $\alpha$ is the phase (in rad) of the sinusoid;
 - $\theta$ is the parameter, which is the angle (in rad) of the generatrix of the cylinder.

You can then convert to a parametric equation in Euclidean coordinates as
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  x = r\cos \theta  \hfill \cr 
  y = r\sin \theta  \hfill \cr 
  z = h\sin \left( {\lambda \theta  + \alpha } \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

example:
[image: Sin_on_Cyl_1]

Comment: This is definitely a fantastic answer. only that I will have to plot it in Python , and based on the code here : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d_radial.html it needs to have the functions also in 3D, I wish someone could help me

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: I recasted the answer with parametric equations you can use for plotting

Comment: @G Cab : YOU ARE SUPER GREAT !! more than what I expected ! thanks a lot

Comment: just one problem, this did not work for me, why ?

Comment: I can't post my code here , too long

Comment: only the definition :

Comment: h= 0.5;
landa= 1;
alfa = 0;
r = np.linspace(0, 1.25, 50)
p = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
R, P = np.meshgrid(r, p)

Z = (h* np.sin(landa*P+alfa))

# Express the mesh in the cartesian system.
X, Y = R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P)

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti:  I'm sorry I don't know the details of Python (not yet, I would like to learn). I obtained the above with my old (but still very good) Mupad as x:=t->r*cos(t):
y:=t->r*sin(t):
z:=t->h*sin(l*t+a):

r:=3: l:=5:  h:=1:  a:=0:

plot(
plot::Cylinder(r,[0,0,-2],[0,0,2],Color=RGB::Yellow),
plot::Curve3d([x(t),y(t),z(t)],t=0..2*PI)
);

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: maybe you can follow [this other py.plot example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/lines3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-lines3d-py)

Comment: Thank you very much, but why in that code, r is a function of Z, instead of Z function of theta, like your formula ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: well, the example is for a paraboloid spiral, not for a cylindrical sinusoid. So just replace r= const. (as $h$ and $\alpha$) and $x,y,z$ as in the answer

Comment: This was the most beautiful answer I got on StackOverFlow.com ! Gold answer !! it worked beautifully ! thank you!!!!!!!!!!